# Synchronizing Visual Studio Code configuration between Windows and Linux with dynamic path handling

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, path, ide, editor

I am using Visual Studio Code as my primary development environment and I rely on the IDE's configuration [synchronization feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) to keep my settings consistent across different environments. However, I've encountered an issue regarding the handling of file paths between Windows/x86 and Linux/arm64 within the settings.json file.

My problem relates to the configuration of the ``` php.validate.executablePath`` option in the **settings.json** file. Currently, I am manually setting the path to the **PHP** executable for each operating system, such as ``` "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"`for Windows and`"/path/to/php"` for Linux.

However, this manual configuration of file paths becomes problematic when synchronizing the configuration between Windows and Linux, as I have to manually make changes to the settings.json file each time I switch environments.

I want to find a way to dynamically handle the file paths in the settings.json file so that I can correctly synchronize the configuration between Windows 10 and Debian GNU/Linux 11 without having to make manual adjustments.

I would like to know if there are any recommended methods or suggestions for dynamically handling file paths in the settings.json file of Visual Studio Code. This way, I can use the correct PHP executable path based on the operating system without requiring manual modifications to the file during synchronization between Windows and Linux.

I have read the article "[PHP in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php)" which provides information about the following settings:

> - **php.validate.executablePath**: points to the PHP
>   executable on disk. Set this if the PHP executable is not on the
>   system path.

However, it is not clear from the article whether it is possible to add a different path based on the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables in a similar way to how Java uses `JAVA_HOME`. For each machine, set a system-level environment variable that points to where the PHP installation to use is, and then use that environment variable in your settings. You can [reference environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables) in your settings.json using `${env:VARNAME}`. Using forward slashes might be fine. If it isn't, then use the `${pathSeparator}` [variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables).

If that doesn't work, you may be interested in the feature-request issue ticket [Allow to scope settings by platform #5595](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5595). If you are, you can give it a thumbs up to show support, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress. But please [avoid noisy comments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) like "+1" or "bump".

Answer (score 0):

I tried something these on setting.json

```
"php.executablePath.windows": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

or

```
"php.executablePath": {
  "windows" : "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
}
```

but it didn't work.

However, I found a solution ( see attached GIF animation ), is possible disable a single setting from sync with **"sync this setting"** unchecked .

To disable the synchronization of specific settings in Visual Studio Code, you can follow these steps:

- Open **Visual Studio Code** and navigate to the **"File"** menu in the main menu bar.
- Select **"Preferences"** and then **"Settings"** to open the Settings panel.
- At the top of the Settings panel, you'll find a **search field**. Enter the name of the setting you want to disable syncing for (e.g., **"php.executablePath"**).
- Locate the setting in the search results and click on the **gear icon ⚙️** positioned next to it.
- In the dropdown menu that appears, uncheck the **"Sync this setting"** option.

[image: Sync this setting]

By unchecking the **"Sync this setting"** option, the specific setting, such as **"php.executablePath"** will no longer be synchronized across devices using **Visual Studio Code**'s settings synchronization feature.

Please note that this method allows you to disable syncing for individual settings, giving you control over which settings get synchronized and which don't.